# Azure Logic App keeps running and wont stop

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a simple logic app which call a Slack webhook when http request is received. 
It's doing the job perfectly but the issue is in the Runs history I can see all the runs' status is "Running". Shall I do something about it?

[image]
If I click on one of the runs I can see that the Http Webhook is still waiting. 

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the Logic App and WebHook Action are working as designed.

The WebHook will stay active until the client, Slack in this case, Unsubscribes.

Maybe you should not be using a WebHook on the Slack service if you want a fully synchronous operation.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. So I replaced the webhook with simple http call.

Comment: @Kamran, Thanks, I am facing same issue with MS Teams, May I ask how did you fix it please ?

Comment: @UtpMahesh, logic app has Http Webhook and Http actions. I used the last one.